# T test on whole sample or on averages

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

**Background:**

Consider the following experiment:

There are two groups of subjects,  Group A have been treated with a drug that affects the muscle fibre diameter and Group B with a placebo. After treatment, a biopsy is performed, and the diameter of a given number of muscle fibres looks like this.

Note that as this is a controlled experiment, the only variation between the subjects is the treatment, and the subjects themselves.

(Note: Random data typed out to illustrate concept, variances do not represent actual data)

```
Treatment A:
  Subject 1: 10,12,15,16,17,20,45       
  Subject 2: 9,11,12,14,15,16,20,37 

Treatment B:
  Subject 3: 21,22,25,26,34,43
  Subject 4: 24,25,25,26,35,40
```

Now, when evaluating the differences by a t test, I have two options:

**Option 1:**

I pool data from subjects 1 &2, and pool separately 3 & 4 and perform a t test on the extended dataset:

So essentially, the groups will be

```
Treated: 21,22,25,26,34,43,    24,25,25,26,35,40
Placebo: 10,12,15,16,17,20,45, 9,11,12,14,15,16,20,37
```

**Option 2:**

I take the averages of the subjects and then perform the T test.

Essentially the groups will be:

```
Treated: 28.5, 29.16,
Placebo: 19.28, 16.75
```

**Question:**

Now, convention (my team) say I go for Option 2, but the thing I am afraid of loosing is the variability within each subject, when I take the average. Can I have your thoughts on this ? I know that neither Option 1 nor 2 are ideal, and am at a loss as to what test to use. For the simplicity of the question, assume normal distribution, and equal variances.

Comment: Manifestly, you do **not** get exactly the same results for each subject, so there is variability, regardless of whether this is a controlled experiment. So, the "option" to average over subjects is just not available without leaving the domain of statistics. Conversely, if in some situation, subjects produce exactly the same measurement repeatedly, then the problem of comparison does not entail a significance test. As a silly example, I can be trusted at present to give the same answer, 5, to the question how many fingers I have on my right hand; so there is no uncertainty to test.

Comment: Naturally, you do have a difficulty in that different subjects appear in each group. Part of the experimental design should be to ensure that subjects in each group are selected to be comparable. If that is not true, post hoc analysis can't save the design.

Comment: We have designed the experiment keeping that in mind, in the sense that all subjects are age and weight matched, and hence are proceeding under the assumption (as almost all studies do) that the subjects between groups are comparable. When you mention post hoc, I presume you are pointing me to do an ANOVA first ?

Comment: Post hoc was probably the wrong term here, as it has a specific meaning after ANOVA. What I meant was that if your subjects are not comparable you can't disentangle differences between subjects and the effects of treatments. If that's obvious, OK.

Comment: Yes, that will be obvious, as the treatment should give about 20% or more change, and inter subject variability when adjusted for weight should not exceed a few percent.